# On load function doesn't work after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

For some reason, after I refresh website, code in .on('load', function()) doesn't want to work. First load is working fine, as intended.

That behaviour started to happen when I introduced loader (animation before page full loads). Before that everything worked just fine.

```
/* Before page loads */
$( function() {
  $('#intro').hide(); 
});


/* After page loads */
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.loader').hide();
  $('#intro').fadeIn(3200);
  includePartials();
  slideOutLandingPage();
});
```

To be specific, problem is that `$('#intro').fadeIn(3200);` doesn't happen and `$('#intro')` still has attribute `display: none;`
Any idea what might be the reason for that? Any idea how to bypass this?

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div id="intro">
      <div class="title">
        <div class="title-block">
          <h1>Pretty website</h1>
          <h2>Click anywhere!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    ...
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are no errors in console.

To your advice, I have added console.log in several places to check order in which they are called, but everything looks like it should.

When I delete `/* Before page loads */` part it works on refresh just fine, but loader is (obviously) still there after loads. Not to mention that my whole structure (formatting) of page goes bad.

Here's how I put console.logs:

```
$( function() {
  $('#intro').hide(); 
  console.log('Before load');
});


/* After page loads */
$(window).on('load', function() {
  console.log('After load 1');
  $('.loader').hide();
  $('#intro').fadeIn(3200);
  console.log('After load 2');
  includePartials();
  slideOutLandingPage();
});
```

**Since many people wrote in here about document ready - it's not the solution. It must specifically work on load.**

Comment: Some HTML code would be helpful.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: if you remove first part of your code and set element style to display none, does it kicks the into animation to fadein?
P.S
why just don't set #into { display: none;}

Comment: Put alerts or console.log in both parts of code to see, if they really running and in which order. http://jsbin.com/siduyovaxi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: in all browsers?

Comment: `#intro {display: none;}` is your preferred way, guy.

Comment: Why my answer is downvoted?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with my loader.

I only used this to make all my container appear after window is loaded (this was my first test)

```
    $(window).on('load',function() {
        // Animate container
        $(".container").animate({opacity:1}, 1500);
    });
```

But it worked the when i reload the page, not when I refresh the page.

I was asking to myself why, but I think I might have the answer...

It's simply because I have this function inside my ready function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() { }
```

If I separate the two, everything work even when I refresh or reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because $("#intro").hide() is called after $("#intro").fadeIn() method. You need to remove calling hide method and append display:none property to the #intro element.

Something like this.

```
<body>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div id="intro">
      <div class="title">
        <div class="title-block">
          <h1>Pretty website</h1>
          <h2>Click anywhere!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
</body>
<style>
    #intro {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(window).on('load', function() {
      $('.loader').hide();
      $('#intro').fadeIn(3200);
      includePartials();
      slideOutLandingPage();
});
</script>
```

Then this will be working.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, it seems to work fine, no?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#intro').hide();
  console.log('Before load');
});


/* After page loads */
$(window).on('load', function() {
  console.log('After load 1');
  $('.loader').hide();
  $('#intro').fadeIn(3200);
  console.log('After load 2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader"></div>
<div id="intro">
  <div class="title">
    <div class="title-block">
      <h1>Pretty website</h1>
      <h2>Click anywhere!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to set intial `display: none` in css then remove "before load" actions and add few lines to on.load

```
/* After page loads */
$(window).on('load', function() {
  console.log('After load 1');
  $('.loader').hide();
  $('#intro').css('display','flex').hide().fadeIn(3200);
  console.log('After load 2');
  includePartials();
  slideOutLandingPage();
});
```

Little crude but works.

Answer (score -3):

`$( function() {` is `document ready` event it is triggered after `$(window).on('load'`.
http://jsbin.com/siduyovaxi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: This is not a solution.
I checked url, yeah that is what I was trying to tell in comments. Could you modify your answer to actually be valid solution

Comment: @Raimonds this is much better - The reason.

Comment: This is also inaccurate.  load happens after ready.  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Taplar have you opened my jsbin example? `Ready` could happen only when everything required is downloaded and ready. `Load` happens as soon as html is parsed (or somewhere here)

Comment: No, that's backwards man.  Read the api.  Or actually make a working example and you will see.  I don't know why your pastebin is doing it backwards, but my answer on this site does it the way in the question and it is working as expected, ready firing before load.

Comment: @Taplar API is nothing if in browser it works in other way. Do you prefer theory or real practice?

Comment: @Anarion .ready gets called either on the DOMContentLoaded event, or immediately if said event has already occured. the window load event occurs when the window load event occurs. the DOMContentLoaded event always happens before the window load event. So, by that logic, yes, it is *possible* for dom ready to be executed without the window load event subsequently being triggered in the event the code runs after both events have occurred. but blanketly stating that document ready happens after window load is simply false/incorrect/wrong.